# What is the best way to wait to next line from a fast-growing file?

Tags: c#, io

I need to read a fast-growing test file, and process any new lines ASAP.
The file can be updated several time per millisecond.

1. If I introduce a sleep at "PROBLEM" line of code (as below), it works nicely but does introduce 1 millisecond delay.
2. If I comment out "PROBLEM" line, I get no delay BUT my CPU usage gets toward 70%.

Is there a better way to resolve this?

```
public void UpdatePricesFromSFile()
{
    using (txtFileReader = new StreamReader(File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite)))
    {
        txtFileReader.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
        while (true)
        {
            while ((line = txtFileReader.ReadLine()) == null)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1); //PROBLEM
            }
            //Process line
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So, what it the problem? Do you want to rewrite your code to "win" 1 millisecond of time? Of course, infinite `while` block without thread sleeping will cause problems. I would even do `Sleep` for 200 ms. Most probably, 199 ms doesn't matter so much.

Comment: You can create a special class in which you store `stream.Position` and implement `FileSystemWatcher` to watch on that particular file. Then whenever file changes just start by checking `if(stream.Length > lastStreamPosition)` and if it is then just use `stream.Position = lastStreamPosition;`. With that you can continue reading the file.

Comment: @m.rogalski Then he doesn't even need to cache the `stream.Position`... The `FileSystemWatcher` can simply `Set` a `ManualResetEvent` or something similar.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev Yes. I ms is key in this application.

Comment: @m.rogalski DO you know if FileSystemWatcher has any overhead? I am really tryign to get something to wait for just a fraction of a millisecond

Comment: @xanatos Yes, you're right. Haven't thought about that when writing this comment. Combining these should give similar result to wait for 1 or maybe 3 ms but wont consume so much resources as specified.

Comment: I see another problem here: how can you have the guarantee that you are reading a whole line? There is no guarantee that line-writes are atomic...

Comment: @xanatos Yes you are correct. I worried about that initially, BUT it does NOT happen ( for me anyway - perhaps because I also create the file I am reading using WriteLine()?). I parse line after ReadLine() with a Try/Catch and I never have had an error.

Comment: @ManInMoon You wouldn't get an error, simply your line would be split in multiple lines (possibly with some of them blank)

Comment: @xanatos Correct. WHat I meant was that I parse all fields of the line - and I would get an error if a field was not in right format to parse. Well, I think so anyway!

Comment: I was hoping there was the equivalent of BlockingCollection's "TryTake". You can create a 1 ms TryTake loop that will fire more quickly if a new item is added to the collection.

Answer (score 0):

Extending my comment with code sample :

```
public abstract class FileWatcher
{
    // last known position of the stream 
    int m_LastStreamPosition;

    // flag to check if file is currently in read state
    volatile bool m_IsReading;

    // info about the file
    FileInfo m_FileInfo;
    // file system watcher 
    FileSystemWatcher m_Watcher;

    // standard ctor used to watch specific file
    public FileWatcher(string filePath)
    {
        // create new instance of FileSystem using the path of the file
        m_FileInfo = new FileInfo(filePath);
        // if ( !m_FileInfo.Exists ) throw new InvalidArgumentException("filePath");
        // start watcher based on the FileInfo
        m_Watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(m_FileInfo.DirectoryName, m_FileInfo.Extension);
        m_Watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        m_Watcher.Changed += WhenFileChanged;

        // reset stream position and read file initialy
        m_LastStreamPosition = 0;
        ReadFile();
    }

    // event fired when file is changed
    // !! note that this will fire whenever you create file in the same
    //    directory as your desired file is and with the same extension
    //    and then change/modify this file
    void WhenFileChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        // based on the note comment, check if that's our desired file
        if ( e.FullPath != m_FileInfo.FullName ) return;

        // refresh informations about the file
        m_FileInfo.Refresh();
        // check if something was added to the file,
        // in case something was removed (?) reset lastStreamPosition (?)
        if ( m_FileInfo.Length <= m_LastStreamPosition )
            m_LastStreamPosition = 0;

        // read the file
        ReadFile();
    }

    void ReadFile()
    {
        if ( m_IsReading ) return;

        m_IsReading = true;

        using ( StreamReader reader = m_FileInfo.OpenText() )
        {
            reader.BaseStream.Position = m_LastStreamPosition;
            string line = string.Empty;
            while ( ( line = reader.ReadLine() ) != null )
            {
                ProcessLine(line);
            }
            m_LastStreamPosition = reader.BaseStream.Position;
        }
        m_IsReading = false;
    }

    protected abstract void ProcessLine(string line);
}
```

Sample usage :

```
public class MeFileWatcher
    : FileWatcher
{
    public MeFileWatcher(string filePath)
        : base(filePath)
    {
    }

    protected override void ProcessLine(string line)
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("NEW LINE ADDED -> {0}", line);
    }
}

MeFileWatcher meFileWatcher = new MeFileWatcher("D:\\testData\\meFile.txt");
```

Comment: Thank you. That's a very different approach to the one I use. I will need to create a test app. Have you used this in any high-performance environment?

Comment: @ManInMoon I use similar class in production code not to read data from the file but to check if something changed and then move to the file repository on FTP.  It works great when you have tons of files but I cannot say it will perform the same with reading.